# Canvas Context Intellisense Missing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, canvas, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

So after some research, this is supposed to work natively in VS2012, but it appears not to be.

```
function myFunc(canvasId) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

}
```

Within this function, if I type "canvas." I get all the intellisense I'd expect. If I type "ctx." I get nothing at all. Just the list of all identifiers in the file with a "sorry" message from visual studio. Is this expected? It would be very helpful to get intellisense on the ctx object, since it has all the canvas drawing functions attached to it.

Also tried declaring ctx outside of myFunc as follows, with same effect.

```
var ctx;    

function myFunc(canvasId) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

}
```

Comment: I suspect your `ctx` is out of scope try moving the variable declaration outside of `myFunc()` and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried, no dice. Updated the original post to show what I attempted.

Comment: I wanted to add some additional info: I do get intellisense for "context." but notably, getContext is missing from that list.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. 
In my case, i forgot the quotes (document.getElementById(myCanvas), "myCanvas" being the id of my canvas element). After i added the quotes (document.getElementById('myCanvas')), the intellisense of ctx appeared. 
Check if the value of your variable "canvasId" is a valid one (not null, undefined etc).